# C++ Program is returning "0" every time?

Tags: c++, xcode

Example of my output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAI3L.jpg
I'm trying to make a simple F to C constructor function type program. Every time I run it though, I get a response of 0. A lot of the problems people have asked about this type of program have to do with them not doubling their (5/9) where I have done this but still get a return of '0'.

```
    /* Mr. Gadaffi
 04.27.17 farenheit to celsius program
 */

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// 1.8 * cel + 32;
// 0.55555 * (far - 32);

double fToC(double tempInFarenheit) {
    double farenheit, celsius;
    farenheit = 1.8 * (celsius + 32);
    return farenheit;
}

double cToF(double tempInCelsius) {
    double farenheit, celsius;
    celsius = (5/9.0) * (farenheit - 32);
    return celsius;
}

int main () {

    string typeOfDegrees;
    double farenheit, celsius;

    cout << "Please enter whether your initial degrees are in Farenheit or Celcius(F or C): " << endl;
    cin >> typeOfDegrees;

        if (typeOfDegrees == "F") {
            cout << "What is the degrees in Farenheit?: " << endl;
            cin >> farenheit;
            cout << "The temperature in Celsius is: " << celsius << " degrees C" << endl;
            celsius = fToC(farenheit);
    }
    else if (typeOfDegrees == "C")
    {
        cout << "What is the degrees in Celsius?: " << endl;
        cin >> celsius;
        cout << "The temperature in Farenheit is: " << farenheit << " degrees F" << endl;
        farenheit = cToF(celsius);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: What did you see when you debugged it? And Nicholas Colan is the master mind behind M. Gaddaffi?

Comment: You are calling your functions after you output the value.. Also you may want to use the values (`tempInFarenheit` and `tempInCelsius`) passed into your functions.

Comment: Are you sure you are not confused? `fToC` returns farenheit, while naming suggests something else. same goes for `CtoF`. also as some already pointed, you are using unused variables.

Answer (score 6):

In C/C++, instruction are executed sequentially. That means, inside a function, line X is done before line X+1. In your case

```
double celcius;

// ...

cout << "The temperature in Celsius is: " << celsius << " degrees C" << endl;
celsius = fToC(farenheit);
```

Thus, you first send celcius to `cout`, and *then* you calculate `celcius`. You probably want to switch those lines :

```
celsius = fToC(farenheit);
cout << "The temperature in Celsius is: " << celsius << " degrees C" << endl;
```

Same thing for celcius -> fahrenheit conversion.

((I know many SO people like to talk about 'undefined behavior', whether the question asker cares about what that is or not. So I will mention, as a "good SO user", that using variables that haven't been initialized is undefined behavior.))

Also, your functions `cToF` and `fToC` don't use the parameter values.

Answer (score 4):

```
double fToC(double tempInFarenheit) { // you forget to use your variable
    double farenheit, celsius; // you create celsius here
    farenheit = 1.8 * (celsius + 32); // so that is 1.8 * (undefined + 32)
    return farenheit;
}

double cToF(double tempInCelsius) { // Same here
    double farenheit, celsius;
    celsius = (5/9.0) * (farenheit - 32);
    return celsius;
}
```

That should do what you want :

```
double fToC(double tempInFarenheit) {
    double farenheit, celsius;
    farenheit = 1.8 * (tempInFarenheit+ 32);
    return farenheit;
}

double cToF(double tempInCelsius) {
    double farenheit, celsius;
    celsius = (5/9.0) * (tempInCelsius- 32);
    return celsius;
}
```

also:

```
  if (typeOfDegrees == "F") {
        cout << "What is the degrees in Farenheit?: " << endl;
        cin >> farenheit;
        cout << "The temperature in Celsius is: " << celsius << " degrees C" << endl; // you send the message here out
        celsius = fToC(farenheit); // and here you are calculating it... that can't work
```

this:

```
  if (typeOfDegrees == "F") {
            cout << "What is the degrees in Farenheit?: " << endl;
            cin >> farenheit;
            celsius = fToC(farenheit);
            cout << "The temperature in Celsius is: " << celsius << " degrees C" << endl;
}
```

Comment: You can make the functions even simpler.  Just have in them `return 1.8 * (tempInFarenheit+ 32);` and `return (5/9.0) * (tempInCelsius- 32);`.

Comment: @NathanOliver sure, there could be done alot more but i want to keep it simple ;)

Answer (score 1):

FYI, the above can be shortened:

```
double fToC(double tempInFarenheit) {
    return (5/9.0) * (tempInFarenheit - 32);
}
```